# How do I tell my Rails app where my CasperJS script is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, casperjs

I want to launch several CasperJS scripts from within my Ruby on Rails app.

I want to know two things:

1. Where should I place the script? (which folder)
2. Do I need to tell Ruby on Rails where CasperJS can be found within my system? If so, how?

Comment: https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem

Comment: @okliv sorry. I meant CasperJS.

Comment: then according to this https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/168 - `gem install casperjs` will be enough (include it in gem file)

Answer (score 1):

If its not a gem, and your using Rails 3.x and up, just place it in

```
/app/assets/javascripts
```

if the

```
require_tree.
```

in the application.js is there it would automagically include everything in the above folder.

If here are issues about the order of inclusion, write

```
//= require xxxxxxx
```

xxxxxxx being the js file name without the extension

and it will be included in top to bottom order.